# Do you include skills in your CV?

Tags: cv, job, faculty-application

In any business CV/resume, the section of skills is a great deal with full descriptions such as

- **Communication skills:** a few sentences of description of relevant
  experience
- **Project management:** separate description

However, I have not seen such emphasis in an **academic CV**. If any, it was a list of software skills at the end with the same weight as the hobbies.

Is it appropriate/useful to put such emphasis on the skills? Or such descriptions are too subjective for an academic CV and should be presented in the cover letter (in a faculty application)?